# Group by based on 3 tables that are joined using left join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Below is my query that fetches the fields based on the left join of 3 tables. My requirement is to get all the fields based on the recent SystemDateTime in table Debug.T. For example, if i try it for HardwareId = 550803413, it returns 2 records with 2 different SystemDateTime. I need to filter it so that I get only 1 record for all HardwareIds based on recent SystemDateTime. Data is stored in Google Big Query.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT HardwareId, e.Carrier, max(d.SystemDateTime) as   DateTime,
CASE
  WHEN lower(DebugData) LIKE 'veri%' THEN 'Verizon'
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(lower(DebugData),'\\d+') THEN c.Network
END
AS ActualData 
FROM (
SELECT 
HardwareId, SystemDateTime, max(SystemDateTime) as max_date,
INTEGER(RTRIM(SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData,'\\"',' '), '\\?',' ') ,0,3))) AS d1, 
INTEGER(RTRIM(SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]',' '),4,LENGTH(DebugData)-3))) AS d2
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([Debug.T],TIMESTAMP('2016-05-16'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-16'))
GROUP BY HardwareId, DebugReason, DebugData, SystemDateTime
HAVING DebugReason = 31) AS d
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT Mcc, Mnc as Mnc, Network from [Debug.Carrier]
) As c
ON c.Mcc = d.d1 and c.Mnc = d.d2
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT VehicleId, APNCarrier FROM [Info_20160516]
) As e
ON d.HardwareId = e.VehicleId
GROUP BY HardwareId, ActualData, e.Carrier
HAVING HardwareId = 550803413
```

Current output:

```
HardwareId  DebugReason DebugData   e_APNCarrier    DateTime    ActualDebugData
550473814   50013   23430"? Unknown 2016-05-16 08:09:09.534597  Everyth. Ev.wh./T-Mobile
550473814   50013   23410"? Unknown 2016-05-16 07:50:48.526288  O2 Ltd.
550473814   50013   23415"? Unknown 2016-05-16 23:54:37.487154  Vodafone
```

Expected output:

Since the recent SystemDateTime is 23:54:37.487154, query should filter the records based on the recent SystemDateTime and provide the result.

```
HardwareId  DebugReason DebugData   e_APNCarrier    DateTime    ActualDebugData
550473814   50013   23415"? Unknown 2016-05-16 23:54:37.487154  Vodafone
```

Comment: Please include db schema, data sample and expected output.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Thanks, edited the question.

Comment: don't see column `d1, d2` in your alias `d`, how can you join with c using `d.d1 and d.d2`?

Comment: Sorry a typo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you just want the latest record per `HardwareId` based on `DateTime`?  Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT HardwareId, e.Carrier, d.SystemDateTime as   DateTime,
CASE
  WHEN lower(DebugData) LIKE 'veri%' THEN 'Verizon'
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(lower(DebugData),'\\d+') THEN c.Network
END
AS ActualData,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HARDWAREID ORDER BY d.SystemDateTime desc) RN 
FROM (
SELECT 
HardwareId, SystemDateTime, max(SystemDateTime) as max_date,
INTEGER(RTRIM(SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData,'\\"',' '), '\\?',' ') ,0,3))) AS d1, 
INTEGER(RTRIM(SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(DebugData,'[^a-zA-Z0-9]',' '),4,LENGTH(DebugData)-3))) AS d2
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([Debug.T],TIMESTAMP('2016-05-16'),TIMESTAMP('2016-05-16'))
GROUP BY HardwareId, DebugReason, DebugData, SystemDateTime
HAVING DebugReason = 31) AS d
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT Mcc, Mnc as Mnc, Network from [Debug.Carrier]
) As c
ON c.Mcc = d.d1 and c.Mnc = d.d2
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT VehicleId, APNCarrier FROM [Info_20160516]
) As e
ON d.HardwareId = e.VehicleId
HAVING HardwareId = 550803413
)
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: I get the error - Field HardwareId not found on either side of the join.

Comment: Just noticed I had a typo in the spelling of `ROW_NUMBER()`.  Fixed it in the code above.  But FYI - I just copied and pasted your query as the inner query removing the `group by`, `max` on `SystimeDateTime` field, and adding the following column to sort your data `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HARDWAREID ORDER BY d.SystemDateTime desc) RN`.